# How to properly connect remote controller POX to mininet

Tags: python, mininet, sdn, openflow, pox

I constructed a simple mininet topology  with two hosts connected to switch controlled by a remote controller pox running the forwarding.L2_learning component. this works fine ping all is good.

Now i change the topology  with two hosts and two switches each host connected to a switch, both switches are connected to the remote pox controller running the same component (forwarding.L2_learning ).

but this time the pingall is not working !! i'm new to mininet and pox.

The python script used to create the mininet topology is below

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import Controller, RemoteController, OVSController
from mininet.node import CPULimitedHost, Host, Node
from mininet.node import OVSKernelSwitch, UserSwitch
from mininet.node import IVSSwitch
from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.log import setLogLevel, info
from mininet.link import TCLink, Intf
from subprocess import call
from time import sleep


def myNetwork():
    net = Mininet(topo=None,
                  build=False,
                  ipBase='10.0.0.0/8')

    info('*** Adding controller\n')
    c0 = net.addController(name='c0',
                           controller=RemoteController,
                           ip='0.0.0.0',
                           protocol='tcp',
                           port=6633)

    info('*** Add switches\n')
    s1 = net.addSwitch('s1', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)
    s2 = net.addSwitch('s2', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)

    info('*** Add hosts\n')
    h1 = net.addHost('h1', cls=Host, ip='10.0.0.1', defaultRoute=None)
    h2 = net.addHost('h2', cls=Host, ip='10.0.0.2', defaultRoute=None)

    info('*** Add links\n')
    net.addLink(h1, s1)
    net.addLink(h2, s2)
    net.addLink(h1, s2)

    info('*** Starting network\n')
    net.build()

    info('*** Starting controllers\n')
    for controller in net.controllers:
        controller.start()

    info('*** Starting switches\n')
    net.get('s1').start([c0])
    net.get('s2').start([c0])

    info('*** Post configure switches and hosts\n')
    net.pingAll()
    net.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setLogLevel('info')
    myNetwork()
```

Comment: How did you create the new topology?

Comment: @SotirisTsartsaris  i used the mininet python API.

Answer (score 1):

The controller I assume is running on localhost though you should replace the

```
ip='0.0.0.0'
```

with

```
c0=net.addController(name='c0',
                      controller=RemoteController,
                      ip='127.0.0.1',
                      protocol='tcp',
                      port=6633)
```

and replace

```
net.addLink(h1, s2)
```

with

```
net.addLink(s1, s2)
```

to connect the 2 switches

Comment: Just found out the error  i was adding the links : net.addLink(h1, s1)    net.addLink(h2, s2) , net.addLink(h1, s2) ; silly error to fix this i replaced net.addLink(h1, s2)  with net.addLink(s1, s2)

Comment: You got me just when I was adding this. You should be ok now.

Comment: just one more question please, what's the best way to run commands on a host (h1 for example)  should i use  h1.cmd() ??

Comment: when first shh from terminal to mininet virtual box pass the -X option for the display and then xterm h1 o mininet cli to open a terminal for h1

Comment: thanks for the xterm solution,  i found what i was looking for using h1.cmd("commands...")  in the API,